# Does adding a reference in a C# / VisualStudio project import the library or simply reference it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need to use an external DLL library within my project. When I add the reference to that library, is my project importing it, or is it just referencing the DLL at its location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, it is a reference to the dll at that location. However once compilation is done, the referenced assemblies may be copied to output directory of your project i.e. next to your project's dll or exe e.g. bin\Release (configurable). You can control this behavior by changing the "Copy Local" property on the reference.

At run time, the assembly is searched for in multiple places such as; the same directory where your primary executable/assembly is placed. See [Locating the Assembly through probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

.NET does not embed the referenced assembly in your exe/dll unless you use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It makes a lot of sense. It would be beneficial to my project if it compiled down to one DLL instead of multiple so I'll look into ILMerge.

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by "import"? Where you think it is imported to? It is a reference. The file gets copied to the output when the reference is told to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I reference DLLs from outside of my project, I have found that the dll file gets copied into by bin/Debug or bin/Release folder. Then, links are resolved at runtime, so while by .exe can be moved around, I still need those DLLs in my path or else I get a "missing reference" error.

This has bitten me a few time when running a C# project via mono on a Linux distribution until I remembered to copy the .dll files over as well. Then it worked fine.